# atom-beautifyで整形ができない

Tags: atom-editor

atom-beautifyで以下のようなエラーがでて整形できません。

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/bin/sqlformat", line 11, in load_entry_point('sqlparse==0.3.1', 'console_scripts', 'sqlformat')() File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlparse-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/sqlparse/cli.py", line 198, in main stream.write(s) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 374-375: ordinal not in range(128)
```

解決方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anacondaやpyenvをすべてアンインストールして、venvにしてjupyter labを触るようにしていたのですが、その兼ね合いで、macからpython3がアンインストールされていたか何かで、python2.7をatomが読み込んでいたみたいですね

https://teratail.com/questions/97050#reply-150290

ここに記載がある

```
process.env.PYTHONIOENCODING = "utf-8";
```

こちらでひとまず解決しました。